# How to Managing multiple custom exceptions in Java

Tags: java, android

Let me explain what i did in java android.

**APPROACH 1:**

I have three  custom exception defined.

```
Public class invalidEmpIDException extends Exception{

    public Integer empID;

    public MyExceptionONE(Integer id) {
        this.empID = id;
    }

    public Integer getEmpID () {
        return this.empID;
    }
}

Public class invalidPermissionEception extends Exception{

    public Integer empID;

    public MyExceptionTWO(Integer id) {
        this.empID = id;
    }

    public Integer getEmpID () {
        return this.empID;
    }
}

Public class MyExceptionTHREE extends Exception{

    public Integer empID;

    public MyExceptionONE(Integer id) {
        this.empID = id;
    }

    public Integer getEmpID () {
        return this.empID;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:

The functions written are  most of the time required to throw all three exceptions for different conditions.**

Example:

```
 public myfunction throws  invalidEmpIDException ,invalidPermissionEception, MyExceptionTHREE
{
  // My Code here..
  // On some condition throws invalidPermissionException,

  // on Some condition throws invalidEmpIDException,

 // on Some cndition throws MyExceptionTHREE..
}
```

Now the consumer writes:

```
try {
    myfunction
} 
catch ( invalidEmpIDException e) 
{
}

catch ( invalidPermissionException e) 
{
}

catch ( MyExceptionTHREE e) 
{
}
```

Initially i felt OK for this approach, but when the situation arrives 
that the user need to call many places the 'myfunction', then this makes code clumsy. Hence i tried the below.

```
catch ( invalidEmpIDException |  invalidPermissionException | MyExceptionTHREE ex ) {
  ex.getEmpID()  
}
```

**PROBLEM-1: Unable to resolve this getEmpID ()**

From the search i found, the above can be resolved by introducing BaseClassExcetion inheriting from Exception and then all other SubClasses from BaseClassException

Hence,

```
public Class BaseException extends Exception 
{
       public Integer empID;

        public BaseException(Integer id) {
            this.empID = id;
        }

        public Integer getEmpID () {
            return this.empID;
        }
    }

}

public Class invalidEmpIDException extends BaseException
{
        public invalidEmpIDException(Integer id) {
            this.empID = id;
        }

        public Integer getEmpID () {
            return this.empID;
        }}


public Class invalidPermissionException extends BaseException
{

        public invalidPermissionException(Integer id) {
            this.empID = id;
        }

        public Integer getEmpID () {
            return this.empID;
        }}
}


public Class MyExceptionTHREE extends BaseException
{


        public MyExceptionTHREE(Integer id) {
            this.empID = id;
        }

        public Integer getEmpID () {
            return this.empID;
        }}
}
```

The above approach solved my **PROBLEM-1**, but leads to another issue  explained below

**QUESTION:**

1) Define a new method  in invaliePermissionException Subclass, which is appropriate for only this class.

```
 Example:     
 public Integer getUserCode() {
 }
```

2) Now How can I use access getUserCode which is so specific to invalidPermissionException in the catch block?

```
  catch ( invalidEmpIDException |  invalidPermissionException | MyExceptionTHREE ex ) {
      ex.getEmpID()  
    }
```

Please Advise me if i need to change my approach, as this is my first attempt in java to work with exceptions.

Comment: Minor side note: if you make your fields public, why add the additional getter methods? I prefer to make them private final; that also helps spotting when they are not correctly initialized. For your actual problem: you could start with having a abstract "base" exception that provides a constructor/getter. Repeating yourself three times .... is basically a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

the approach to use the multi catch works because `ex` will be of the most common type that all the exceptions do have. In your case it would be the `BasicException`. If you want to do different things with the different exceptions you should go back to the first approach with seperate catch block, since you wont be able to access every specific method definded in your custom Exception classes.

As Jägermeister statet, another approach could be the use of a abstract class so that you would only need to call `createExceptionMessage` and would make your other exceptions create the implementation of this method.:

```
 public abstract class CustomBaseException extends Exception{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    abstract void createExceptionMessage();

    public class Ex1 extends CustomBaseException {

        @Override
        void createExceptionMessage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public class Ex2 extends CustomBaseException {

        @Override
        void createExceptionMessage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have any link to read further, and what is the purpose of serialVersionUID?. It is fine if i follow this approach ? http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/05/best-practices-for-for-exception-handling/